# What do the small-sunrise / big-sunrise icons mean on F5 and F6 on the MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

What do the F5 and F6 keys do on the 2011 MacBook Air?  They are marked with what I interpret to be small-sunrise and big-sunrise icons.  I do not see any effect when I press them.

Comment: I interpreted them to be "speedometer icon", and almost thought it is for making the processor run faster or slower

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are for decreasing and increasing the brightness of the keyboard backlight. When the system senses low light and the keyboard is allowed to illuminate, the keys will work. Otherwise, they silently do nothing at all.

[image]